# How to get all the latitude and longitude of a route from location A(start point) to Location B(destination point)

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, google-play-services

I have tried creating routes but I am not sure how to fetch all the latitude and longitude from start point to destination in prior. Here, I select a route of my choice when I search the route from start to destination in the map and I want to get all the latitude and longitude from start to destination. I have to give this data to other java methods for some calculation. Let me know if there are any work around. Since, I am a beginner in Maps I do not have much idea. I had googled and tried in Stack overflow and did not find any similar or supporting solutions.

Thanks in advance,
Ash

Comment: https://github.com/polok/RouteDrawer Check this link

Comment: I heard this cannot be used for autonomous vehicles. Can I use google in my company app for getting directions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all we will get source and destination points between which we have to draw route. Then we will pass these attribute to below function.**

```
 public String makeURL (double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat, double destlog ){
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
    urlString.append("?origin=");// from
    urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString
            .append(Double.toString( sourcelog));
    urlString.append("&destination=");// to
    urlString
            .append(Double.toString( destlat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString( destlog));
    urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
    urlString.append("&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
    return urlString.toString(); }
```

**This function will make the url that we will send to get Direction API response. Then we will parse that response . The parser class is**

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
// constructor
public JSONParser() {
}
public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        json = sb.toString();
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    return json;

}}
```

**This parser will return us string. We will call it like that.**

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

**Now we will send this string to our drawpath function. The drawpath function**

```
public void drawPath(String  result) {

try {
        //Tranform the string into a json object
       final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
       JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
       JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
       JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
       String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
       List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);
       Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                .addAll(list)
                                .width(12)
                                .color(Color.parseColor("#05b1fb"))//Google maps blue color
                                .geodesic(true)
                );
       /*
       for(int z = 0; z<list.size()-1;z++){
            LatLng src= list.get(z);
            LatLng dest= list.get(z+1);
            Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude), new LatLng(dest.latitude,   dest.longitude))
            .width(2)
            .color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
        }
       */
} 
catch (JSONException e) {

}}
```

**Above code will draw the path on mMap. The code of decodePoly is**

```
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
int lat = 0, lng = 0;

while (index < len) {
    int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
    do {
        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (b >= 0x20);
    int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
    lat += dlat;

    shift = 0;
    result = 0;
    do {
        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (b >= 0x20);
    int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
    lng += dlng;

    LatLng p = new LatLng( (((double) lat / 1E5)),
             (((double) lng / 1E5) ));
    poly.add(p);
}

return poly;}
```

**As direction call may take time so we will do all this in Asynchronous task. My Asynchronous task was**

```
private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String url;
connectAsyncTask(String urlPass){
    url = urlPass;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.show();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    return json;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);   
    progressDialog.hide();        
    if(result!=null){
        drawPath(result);
    }
}}
```

**Try This Code it work for me**

Comment: Thanks Vishal, I got a brief idea now. So, we will have to do so much work around to get the lat long, is it?

Comment: PolylineOptions has protected access. How to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this API to get direction Put your starting lat,long and destination lat long into api
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
                + output + "?" + parameters;